# problem while looping through assets folder :(

Tags: android

i have a subfolder in the Assets folder called images where i store my images(of course) :) The things is that i want to get the name for the images which i'm getting but the problem is that i'm also getting other unknown names like: "android-logo-mask.png" which i guess are android's default images. Is there a way i can skip this "android default images" to get only the names of my images? My plan is to save this names in a database to use it as reference for showing the images later on an ImageView. Is it a good idea to use the image name to show the images? Here is some code if it needs:

```
    Context context;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            context = this.getApplicationContext();
            ImageHelper i = new ImageHelper();
            i.readImages(context);
     }

    public class ImageHelper {
 public ImageHelper(){}

 public void readImages(Context context){
  AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
  try {
   String[] getImages = am.list("images");
   for(String imgName : getImages){    
    Log.e("IMAGE NAME----->", imgName);    
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any special reason you don't use the `drawable` directory?

Comment: i have my icons in the drawable directory and i don't want to mix them with the app images. And besides, can make folders and loop through them in the drawable directory?

Answer (score 9):

Use some other name for images folder like "MyImages". It should work fine then.

Comment: This answer had a negative score when I came here, but this is what worked for me. Calling the folder "images" in my assets directory added "android-logo-mask.png" and one other file, but calling it by another name fixed this issue.

Comment: It works for me, while I use the "images" as the folder name, I cannot get the right images list, just one: "android-logo-mask.png" which does not exist at all. After change the name "images" to “sampleImages” , I got the correct ones! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`"images"` should be a path like `"/path/assets/images/image.png"`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)

Comment: Correct. It should be a path inside the assets dir.

Comment: then that's exactly how i have it but i'm still getting the other images too.

Comment: Try using a path to a concrete file as suggested in javadoc.

Comment: do you mean String[] list = am.list("images/image.png"); if so, i can't do that because i have 900 images :(

Comment: Yes, thats what javadoc suggests.

Answer (score 2):

It is very interesting. Even if you don't have an assets/images directory, when you use:

```
myImageList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list("images"));
```

you'll see android-logo-mask.png and android-logo-shine.png listed in the results.

That led me to wondering where those actual image files live in the Android code. I don't know the code base at all, but:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/assets/images/

lists those two in an assets directory *under res*. (Different from the assets directory where I store my project assets, that's not under res).

Being required to provide a path to an individual file for the AssetManagers `list` method (which returns an *array*) just doesn't make any sense. And the method documentation says:

> Return a String array of all the assets at the given path.

It makes me wonder if there's an error in the list method, or if there was some other reason it was designed to return particular system assets when an asset list is required.

In a similar fashion, if I use:

```
myAssetList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list(""));
```

I see "sounds" and "webkit" included, which don't correspond to any existing subdirectory of my assets.

Answer (score 1):

If it occurs that the system adds files in this "images" folder, why not create a new folder for your images that you are sure to contain only your files ?

Comment: that's what i just did. I created an image folder and have images there, String[] getImages = am.list("images");
then i looped through them but i'm still getting another images, it's like it loops through assets recover some names from there and then it loops through my directory. I don't understand what's happening :( it's wierd